# How can I print a very long string completely in R?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have an output of a tibble_df in Rstudio as given below.

```
> austenBooksChapters
# A tibble: 275 x 2
# Groups:   book [6]
   book             chapter                                                           
   <fct>            <chr>                                                             
 1 Sense & Sensibi~ "sense and sensibility\n\nby jane austen\n\n(1811)\n\n\n\n\n"     
 2 Sense & Sensibi~ "\n\n\nthe family of dashwood had long been settled in sussex.  t~
 3 Sense & Sensibi~ "\n\n\nmrs. john dashwood now installed herself mistress of norla~
 4 Sense & Sensibi~ "\n\n\nmrs. dashwood remained at norland several months; not from~
 5 Sense & Sensibi~ "\n\n\n\"what a pity it is, elinor,\" said marianne, \"that edwar~
 6 Sense & Sensibi~ "\n\n\nno sooner was her answer dispatched, than mrs. dashwood in~
 7 Sense & Sensibi~ "\n\n\nthe first part of their journey was performed in too melan~
 8 Sense & Sensibi~ "\n\n\nbarton park was about half a mile from the cottage.  the l~
 9 Sense & Sensibi~ "\n\n\nmrs. jennings was a widow with an ample jointure.  she had~
10 Sense & Sensibi~ "\n\n\nthe dashwoods were now settled at barton with tolerable co~
# ... with 265 more rows
```

Each row represents a chapter of Jane Austen novels.
I want to see the whole chapter string for any single observation.

I could get the desired output by printing as a data frame as given below. Say for chapter-24.

```
as.data.frame(austenBooksChapters)[24,]
```

The above line prints the whole string or chapter in this case in the output.
Is there any way to print the output instead of converting it to data frame.

Comment: You could try `pull`.

Comment: I guess you need `print(width = Inf)`. Otherwise could you please `dput(head(austenBookChapters))`

Comment: I had tried print(width = Inf). This also prints a part of the statement. dput(head(austenBookChapters)) prints all.

Comment: please provide some rows of your df.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the printing properties of tibbles, if you want to look at a particular value you can use it as a vector. For example, to view a particular `Chapter` value you can do.

```
austenBooksChapters$chapter[24]
```